# Check if text exist in div using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to check if the text exist in the div element, so that if text matches the text in div it will alert "hello". May I know how am I able to achieve this result? Thank you.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var text = "div[style*=\"width: 550px;\"]";
        if (#content.indexOf(text) > -1){
            alert("Hello");
        }
    });
  </script>
  <div id="content">
    <div style="width:550px;">James</div>
    <div style="width:500px;">Amy</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Open you browser console. You will see an error like this **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"** Which seems to be pointing to this line `(#content.indexOf(text) > -1)`

Comment: The "text" you are searching for is part of the HTML source, not part of the DIV's text content. Your `text` variable contains a CSS/jQuery style selector, not the actual string you want to search for.

Comment: are you trying to check if a div contains style="width:550px;" ?

Comment: @TusharTyagi yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/9kLnvyqm/

```js
if($('#content').text().length > 0) {  // Checking the text inside a div

  // Condition to check the  text match
  if($('#content').text().indexOf('Amy')){
   console.log('Hello');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div style="width:550px;">James</div>
  <div style="width:500px;">Amy</div>
</div>
```

If you want only the text content from a container then use `text()`, if you are looking for html content then use `html()`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: From the code in the question, it appears the OP is trying to search for an element with a specific style.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the value of inline style of an element.

```js
var wid = $("#content > div")[0].style.width;
if(wid === "550px"){
  //correct width detected. you can use alert instead of console.log
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div style="width:550px;">James</div>
  <div style="width:500px;">Amy</div>
</div>
```

You have multiple elements inside #content. you may want to use the return value of

```
$('#content').children().length;
```

and loop the program to get inline width of all elements. Ping if you need some help with the loop